# Changing Radgrid value changes other

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a Radgrid with column that can has a 2 values: YES or NO. Value is presented in label and when I doublcick on this cell, it changes into combobox, so user can choose from yes or no. Now, I want to achieve something like this: when I set one row to YES i want all other rows set to NO. So it will be always only one row with value YES. I hope you understand me. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to loop through the items and access them http://www.telerik.com/forums/loop-through-rows-of-radgrid-and-retrieve-cell-values

Another option is, since each row is a data item, to modify the datasource accordingly and Rebind() the grid.